# Change assembly color in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

How can I change color in Forge Viewer when I select assembly? Do I need select all parts under assembly and change color? I know how to change one part color. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the `SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT` and recursively (available in Viewer v6.5+) apply a theming color to the components by their `dbid`:

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, event=>{
    viewer.setThemingColor(event.dbIdArray[0], THREE.Vector4, null, true) //last boolean to toggle recursiveness
}) 

viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, event=>{
   ... //multiple models
})
```

See doc for `setThemingColor` [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#setthemingcolor-dbid-color-model).

Comment: Thanks for answer. This is I know. I use this method: ```setColor(viewer,color){
        for (const i of viewer.getSelection()) {
            this.viewer.setThemingColor(i,color,null,true); 
        }
    }``` ,but if I select id which is sub-assembly? Do i have to find all children under sub-assembly and change color every part independently?

Comment: That’s where the last arg - the Boolean to toggle whether to recursively traverse children and set their color

Comment: Sorry a made mistake, I used older version of Viewer api v6.4+. The api v6.5+ is coloring sub-assembly ok, but in v6.4. I used uncoloring (set to default color) and now I can not use it (in v6.5.) ```viewer.setThemingColor(viewer.getSelection(),null,null,true);```. How I can reset color to default only for selected part?

Comment: Use `viewer.clearThemingColors` but there's unfortunately no built-in ability for now to reset color for specific parts only.